# Electrical field energy, decoherent light, and the central limit theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, statistics

The energy density of the electrical field is proportional to its square. It's also proportional to number of photons. From this we see that each additional photon should increase the strength of the field by less and less the more photons there already are. More precisely, the relation is:

$$
N \propto E^2
$$

Where $N$ is the number of photons and $E$ is the magnitude of the electric field. This makes sense, and can be fully explained by thinking of the vibration of a particular mode in the electric field as a quantum harmonic oscillator. But that's for coherent light. For decoherent light, the same relation holds, but the explanation is different.

For decoherent light, the expected (vector) value of the electric field is zero: $\langle \vec E \rangle=0$. So the variance (in, say, the x direction) is $\langle E_x^2 \rangle$. The electric field is linear, so we should just be able to add up the random contributions from each of the photons of various polarization, wavelengths, and phases. By the central limit theorem, the variance will be proportional to $N$. So again, we have:

$$
N \propto \langle E^2 \rangle
$$

It seems like the two explanations are completely different. Is there some unifying principle that explains them both? Would it even be a problem if they were different? I can't think of a paradox that would be caused, but perhaps there is one.

Comment: The first thing which comes to my mind is the description of mixtures, as they are used in QM. In QM we use the density matrix to describe mixtures. It might be interesting to look into this.